# Which preposition to use with "juxtaposed"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Are things *juxtaposed to* or *juxtaposed with* other things?

> 1. The slimy seaweed was startling, juxtaposed *to/with* the hot smooth sand.
> 2. I moved the painting to the other wall so that it would be juxtaposed *to/with* the sculpture that inspired it.

Does the side-by-side nature of *juxtapose* dictate this, or does it depend on the perceived relationship between the elements?

Comment: I think [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juxtaposed+to+the%2Cjuxtaposed+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) implies it doesn't matter. Check the underlying books to be sure though.

Comment: x is *in juxtaposition to* y in my experience, but I think *juxtaposed with* is correct for that form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [Ngrams show](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=juxtaposed%20to,juxtaposed%20with,juxtaposed%20against&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), you can get away with juxtaposed *with*, *to*, or *against*.  I prefer *with* because *to* implies some sort of subject-object or other asymmetrical relationship while *with* is used when the relationship is symmetrical.  "I am talking *to* you" is different than "you are talking *to* me" and both are different than "I am talking *with* you."  "A is juxtaposed with B" is the same as "B is juxtaposed with A."

It doesn't really make sense for one thing to be juxtaposed *to* the other except maybe in the case where one is talking about the physical act of moving A next to B.  I would guess that people using *to* are referring to that literally or figuratively. Not only *I juxtaposed the painting to the sculpture that inspired it* but also *We've been talking about the poverty of the bottom 10%, which is bad enough, but when that is juxtaposed to the wealth of the top 10% how can you not be outraged?*

Still, I would use *with* exclusively.

Comment: I think an asymmetrical vs. a symmetrical relationship (examples #1 vs. #2 respectively) is precisely what makes the difference. Which leads me to prefer "against" for #1, and "with" for #2.

Comment: @ChrisNoe I can see the case for "juxtaposed against", particularly if you are putting a small thing in front of a big thing. FWIW, NOAD uses this sentence as the example of how to use "juxtapose": _black-and-white photos of slums were starkly juxtaposed with color images._ If you used "against" instead of "with" in that sentence as part of a larger article that you asked me to edit, I would not tell you to change "against" to "with".

Answer (score 8):

The Corpus of Contemporary American English has the [top 3 collocates for *juxtaposed*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=16397572):

```
1 JUXTAPOSED WITH    201
2 JUXTAPOSED TO      54
3 JUXTAPOSED AGAINST 49
```

So *juxtaposed with* is most common, with *juxtaposed to* and *juxtaposed against* about 1/4 as common.

My personal preference is *juxtaposed against*.

Answer (score 1):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* (16th edition, p. 254) has an entry for *juxtapose* in its "List of words and the prepositions construed with them":

> juxtapose (vb.): to (not *with*)

The *McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs* has [an entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/juxtapose+to) for *juxtapose to* but not for *juxtapose with* or *against*. Finally, the estimable Yahoo Answers community [prefers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090314150055AAGSqXY) *juxtaposed to* to *juxtaposed with*.

Whether or not it makes sense (the rules governing prepositions are arbitrary anyway), *juxtaposed to* is at least defensible, and it's my preference.

Answer (score 0):

Juxtapose with is more common where I come from though juxtapose to is also heard.

Comment: Please see the [help], especially [how to answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You could also check out the edit help (the little ? in a circle above the answer box) to see how to insert markdown - in this case *juxtapose* should be enclosed in asterisks.